# How do i compare 2 string Lists and return boolean index

Tags: python, string, indexing, boolean, compare

How to Compare List of Strings and create a List of booleans to index over

i think its possible with a loop, but i search for a simple function

```
l1 =["a","b", "c"]
l2 =["b", "a"]

index = []
for i in l1:
    index.append(i=l2)
```

expected output:
[True, True, False]

Comment: Are you expecting `[value in l2 for value in l1]`?

Comment: Yes you can simply do, `code`index = [value in l2 for value in l1]`code` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
l1 =["a","b", "c"]
l2 =["b", "a"]

index = []
for i in l1:
    index.append(i in l2)
```

The loop is for every element of l1 and the if checks if the same element of l1 present in l2 or not. If it exists in l2 then `True` is appended else `False` is appended.

Comment: Or without conditions, simply `index.append(i in l2)`

Comment: Yes that will be better

Answer (score 1):

Just a normal list comprehension would work

```
>>> [e in l2 for e in l1]
[True, True, False]
```